# Three JS Inexpensive Crowd using sprites and spritesheets

Tags: 3d, three.js, sprite, sprite-sheet

I'm working on a three.js project that requires me to create a **large crowd of people** as part of a visualisation.

I have determined that using sprites as opposed to 3d models will be an ok solution for performance, since I can, in theory, have photorealistic people with a minimal performance hit.

I have had reasonable success in creating a particle system with many of the same sprite of a woman. Obviously though, the illusion is lost when the camera moves and the woman continues to face the camera. That said, here is my question:

### Part One - Spritesheets

Is there a way that I can make three.js **adjust** the visible section of (or replace) the actual **image** used for the sprite **depending on the angle from which the camera looks at it** in relation to a specified object direction?

This technique is noticeable in many video games such as Mario Kart 64, where images of an advanced 3D model are simply snapped from many angles and included in a large spritesheet. The character images are replaced as needed with the correct part of the sheet to create the illusion of a high quality a character.

[Mario Kart 64 video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aundeN2eX_E) (Notice the clever use of sprites for characters and items)
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aundeN2eX_E

[image: Mario Kart 64 Sprite]

This illusion would be quite perfect for my case, as the photorealistic quality of the people in the crowd combined with the smooth performance will easily make up for the slightly jarring visual effect of "jumping" from one angle to the next, especially as the crowd will not be the primary focus.

### Part Two - Particle Systems

If this is possible, is there a way that I can then create a particle system of these special sprite objects to fill a desired area with people at a low cost in terms of performance?

**Side Notes**

- (Ideally, I would, of course like this area to be populated with a selection of DIFFERENT people from part one, but something tells me this will be the least of concerns)
- (as another side note, my initial test scene produced some weird effects when looking through a transparent section of a sprite at many others - only some would be rendered - though I am still researching this issue)

---

I very much appreciate any help on this topic. I'm afraid my knowlege of three.js just isn't up to par with what I need to do here. If none of this is possible, would anyone perhaps have any other suggestion as to how to create the illusion of a large crowd of people without the drastic performance cost of rendering out hundreds of complex 3d models.

Thanks you very much in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Interesting! And a lot of stuff to consider, so instead of writing a wall of text here's just a brain dump from my side:

- THREE.ParticleSystem renders with GL_Point, you got that figured out.
- The particle system just renders flat. But you need to take camera height into account and therefore the angle between camera and the person, and distort the image to make the perspective look right. I did something similar for my foliage engine: `viewHeight = cos(atan(abs(cameraPosition.y - position.y) / length(position.xz - cameraPosition.xz)));`
- Having the person from several 360° (let's say 8 angles) you'd have 45° between each image. To cover that I would calculate the distance between camera and point (in the fragment shader) and take a normal map into account to perform some light calculations in there! Just for those who are near, and you can use the same normal map for every character :) (maybe it's not worth it though, so I'd omit it at first)
- A simple walk & stand animation for a character would be `(2 (walk) + 1 (stand)) * 8 (angles) = 24 images per character`, plus that one normal map. So my suggestion for having different characters is to render them from a 3D model onto a sprite sheet and just retexture them in order to have several different characters.
- You want your characters to walk around, right? For that you need

  - depth sorting enabled on your particle system
  - dynamic positions, since you update them all the time from the calculated new positions (which is the "naive" way, the nicer way in this case would be DataTextures).

The (relatively small) downsides that come to my mind:

- Sprites have transparency, and you have depth sorting. That's also a bit of a performance hit
- People walk through each other (otherwise your performance would go downhill)

Btw: In 3D terms a spritesheet is a "texture atlas", and you'd have "texture atlas lookups" for your spritesheet in the fragment shader.

I'll write more about it tomorrow if stuff comes to my mind :) gl hf!

Comment: Wow! Thanks for the hasty and involved reply Buddy. Let me have a look through what you've said in depth and most likely hit you back with a reply of that's OK. Might be tomorrow. (Also- actually, for now, I actually don't need them to move around. Fewer lookups for my "texture atlas" and the depth sorting looks like it probably explains what I said in the side notes about the transparent sprites appearing incorrectly)

Comment: I'm working away here with reasonable success. I've gotten a sprite in with 34 frames of a png circling 180 degrees. I'm adjusting the UV offset to select which "frame" I want. One we get past 180, I'm doing the same thing, but flipping the UV scale to -1 to "flip" the image on the horizontal plane. I'm using two keys to trigger this "rotation" This is all dandy, but now I have to work out how to get this to happen in relation to the camera position. I'm not the best with maths but your foliage engine code quote looks like its' up the right alley. Can you elaborate on how I can use this a bit?

Comment: Sorry was away for a few days. Anyway, the code I provided is just for defining the actual height of the billboard on the screen. E.g. if you look top-down with your camera onto your people the angle would be 0 and the people would not be visible. If you look at them with 90° the billboard would have full height. The provided code has nothing to do with selecting the right sprite :) That one I leave with you, Sir, but what you basically want to figure out the angle between the person's walking direction and the camera angle, so you can select the sprite which "faces" the camera the most!

Comment: No problem at all. Indeed, there's some simple enough maths to be done to get the angles of view worked out. That won't be a biggie, however, making a particle system of these things is another story. I don't think it's going to be possible as a particle within a system is essentially a copy of the same material. IE: if I change the material, I change it for ALL the particles. I've parked it for now under time pressure and am doing the crowd with a a system of simple sprites. But for multiple people I need multiple systems: I'm having sorting/rendering issues there. Will possibly consult S.O.!

Comment: Haha nono, you didn't get the purpose of a TextureAtlas! ^^ You'd have all your different people on there (up to a size of 4096x4096px at least) and you'd just provide an index as attribute for every particle which indicates what "personID" it should use :) You'd therefore never change the particle, only the attribute indicating that id! Anyway, sure, post it on SO and drop a link here if you do so. In the meantime please consider accepting my answer if it helped you with your question :)

Comment: It sure has helped! No single answer could have tackled the spectrum of issues, so answer accepted, sir. Ah! I see what you mean now about the texture atlas. I thought you meant using it to select which angle to shoot from with these "3d sprites". What you suggest is, in fact a great solution to the multiple person problem: better than how I have implemented it with several particle system geometries. I didn't need to consult SO in the end as I found  pMaterial.alphaTest = 0.5; did the trick for multi-system sorting. The only thing left when I get time is this multi angled "3d sprite" thing.